# How to get the download URL from firebase with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I would like to retrieve the Download URL of a private image in firbase storage.

Hi have tried many of the suggestions on the site, but all of them end up in the same result.

I have tried the following code:

```
getImageNow() async {
    StorageReference ref =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("/1.jpg");
    String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
    return url;
  }
```

It works when i print the url inside the function, but when i try to call `print(getImageNow())`to get the url, i just get `"Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'"`

UPDATE*************

In the end i am trying to get somthing like this:

```
return Image.network(
  getImageNow(),
);
```

But i can not get it to work with async.

Answer (score 2):

Since `getImageNow()` is asynchronous (as indicated by the `async` keyword), you will need to use `await` to make the calling code wait for the result:

```
print(await getImageNow())
```

What `await` does here is that it essentially unwraps the `Future` and is equivalent to:

```
getImageNow().then((value) => print(value));
```

Comment: Thank You! i have added something else to my question. Do you think you can help?

Comment: Same as in my answer: if a function is marked `async` and you want to use the value from the `Future` it returns, you need to mark the call to that function with `await`, or use `then()` to unwrap the `Future`.

Comment: I am not able to use  `print(await getImageNow())`. i get `Unexpected text 'await'`

Comment: That sounds like you haven't marked the method that calls `await getImageNow()` as `async` itself. I highly recommend reading the Dart page on async programming, as it explains the core concepts that you're dealing with: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures

Answer (score 1):

this is how i upload and get the download url

this part is how i get image from picker

```
 Future getImage() async {
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  setState(() {
    _image = image;
      print('Image Path $_image');
  });
}
```

then i upload it

```
 Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {

  String fileName = basename(_image.path);
  StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
  StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;


  final String url = (await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
  print('URL Is $url');
}
```

hope it will help someone